# PHP/JS library for PDFs: marking, annotating, commenting

Tags: library, javascript, pdf, php

I am looking for a **PHP/JS library** with that would allow my users to:

- view a PDF file
- mark text (selecting)
- mark document fragments (let's say, with a semi-transparent rectangle
  or circle)
- add annotations (or comments) to the marked fragments
- reply to annotations (or comments)
- save (generate) the modified PDF

**What I have**

My web application is running on LAMP (PHP 5.3.3). Currently, I am using **[PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)** as the PDFs viewer.

**Budget**

Open source solution that I can implement myself would be perfect. However, I would also consider premium software.

**What I'm aware of**

I did some research and nowadays the problem is mostly addressed with HTML5 document viewers, like **[GroupDocs](http://groupdocs.com/apps/annotation/live-demo)**, **[Prizm Content Connect](https://www.accusoft.com/products/prizm-content-connect-pcc/overview/)**, **[Crocodoc](https://crocodoc.com/why-crocodoc/)**, etc. -- Nice software, crazy prices.

Also, there are well-known PHP libraries for generating PDFs, like **[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)** or **[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)**. -- Open source, but might not be enough for my needs.

**Finally**

Do you know any software or library that would help me achieve my goal? Do you know any alternative solution? Maybe there's a way to put all I need together using a PHP-HTML5-JS combo in some way?

Answer (score 1):

We're using the premium [SetaPDF](https://www.setasign.com/) components at work and are very happy with the results. From what I know, you can achieve what you want using it. You can see in their demos a "PDF content selection" and the library supports extracting text (for example) from a given region. Worth a try considering you can evaluate the library before a purchase.